# SQL - Obtener el ultimo domingo del mes actual y siguiente

Tags: sql, oracle

soy nuevo en SQL por lo que no se como realizar esta consulta, como puedo obtener por medio de un select el ultimo domingo del mes actual y del siguiente, digamos para obtener el ultimo domingo de este mes (25/10/2020) y el del otro mes (29/11/2020) y que pueda servir para calcular el ultimo domingo de cualquier mes de cualquier año

Comment: pero vos queres un query que devuelva eso o una funcion o que cosa? sql no es para esas cosas... aunque se puede hacer con un sp o una funcion de la db...

Comment: un query, algo parecido al "select sysdate from dual" pero en vez del sysdate algun comando o algo que me permita saber lo que quiero

Comment: select last_day(sysdate) - to_char(last_day(sysdate),'D') + 1 from dual;
Esta consulta hace en parte lo que quiero pero no se como hacer que muestre el del siguiente mes, osea no se como sumarle un mes y en base a ese nuevo mes se calcule el ultimo domingo